# Receiving Your app is violating the following Platform Terms 4.f

Tags: ios, facebook

I am using facebook social login in my iOS app. And I received this email from Facebook but I don't know how to resolve it.

> Hi,
> Your app [my app id] doesn't follow our policies. Since we're striving to improve the Platform experience, your app has been deactivated.
> Your app is violating the following Platform Terms or Developer Policies:
> Platform Terms 4.f: You will maintain publicly available links to your privacy policies in the privacy policy field in the settings of your App Dashboard, as well as in any App Store that allows you to do so, if applicable, and ensure the links remain current and up to date.

I already inserted the privacy policy URL in my **Settings > Basic > Privacy Policy URL**, but I can't find any other place to insert or maintain the policy URL as Facebook said.

Is there anything that I missed?

Comment: Have you added your privacy policy to the Apple App Store?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, since if the app has no privacy policy the app can not be published to the AppStore :(

Comment: Try and use the debug tool to see if Facebook can read your privacy URL without any major problems. They do test its public availability using the same scraper technology, and if it fails for some reason, then it is considered missing/invalid. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: @wallah did you solve this problem?  i got the same problem, but i dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

I have checked with Facebook Developers Operations Team and they replied like this "Currently your apps GooglePlaystore page does not feature any Privacy policy link for review for users. Per our platform policies, please update this page with a link to your apps policy on data protection."

So in the PlayStore you need to completed the Privacy Policy section in the "App Content" category. once you give the URL and your review completes you can reply to the Facebook email to check again.

Comment: Was adding the links in the dashboard enough? I've added them and facebook folks are still complaining.

Answer (score 2):

i have solved this problem by implement "[Data Deletion Request Callback](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app/app-dashboard/data-deletion-callback/)"
and provide service in facebook authen setting. Delete request Data Url.

Comment: could you expand the answer perhaps adding steps on how you did that